# Evolution of DevOps?

Tags: continuous-delivery

I head that the present DevOps jobs were previous know as build and release engineer. I want to go back to past 10 years. What would be the different job position roles a personal might have played from past 10 yes?

Answer (score 6):

I don't view DevOps as a job position. Yes, I also have job offers out there for titles like "DevOps Engineer" [sic], but that just means I am looking for people who mainly can take a team with little DevOps knowhow and guide them along (be it through just doing the bulk of the work, or evangelism or whatever). But at the end of the day, everybody on the team needs to have a working understanding at least of what's going on.

DevOps is more of a feeling, a culture, and a set of common tools and techniques. A guideline if you wish. With memes like having the same environment across dev, qs, prod, immutable containers being shipped across all those, "everything as code", applying Agile and Lean to ops, having devs and ops in the same team and such.